# What does "SELECT INTO" do?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm reading sql code which has a line that looks like this:

```
SELECT INTO _user tag FROM login.user WHERE id = util.uuid_to_int(_user_id)::oid;
```

What exactly does this do? The usual way to use SELECT INTO requires specifying the columns to select after the SELECT token, e.g.

```
SELECT * INTO _my_new_table WHERE ...;
```

The database is postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line must appear inside of a PL/pgSQL function. In that context the value from column `tag` is assigned to variable `_user`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

> Tip: Note that this interpretation of SELECT with INTO is quite different from PostgreSQL's regular SELECT INTO command, wherein the INTO target is a newly created table.

and

> The INTO clause can appear almost anywhere in the SQL command. Customarily it is written either just before or just after the list of select_expressions in a SELECT command, or at the end of the command for other command types. It is recommended that you follow this convention in case the PL/pgSQL parser becomes stricter in future versions.

Comment: Ah right, I thought so.
So the variable _user will be the value of the first row?

Comment: Correct. The title of the section in the documentation is "Executing a Query with a Single-row Result", so that is its intended purpose. In your case, which is apparently about user credentials, that would be the expected return from the query.